# Внедрение нейронной сети в приложение

Tags: java, android, pytorch

Пытаюсь внедрить нейронную сеть в приложение на Android.

Получаю такую ошибку:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
 Process: com.samsung.itschool.firereconize, PID: 1442 
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.samsung.itschool.firereconize/com.example.typeofskin.MainActivity}: com.facebook.jni.CppException: [enforce fail at inline_container.cc:209] . file not found: archive/constants.pkl 
 (no backtrace available) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3780) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3956) 
 at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2295) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8443) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:596) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 
 Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: [enforce fail at inline_container.cc:209] . file not found: archive/constants.pkl
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Версия PyTorch 1.8.0

Версия Java 11

Comment: не найден файл: archive/constants.pkl